# function not getting called using window.attachevent in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm using the below html script, but seems the function is not getting called in IE8

```
<script>
    if (!window.addEventListener) {
        window.attachEvent("onload",abc);
    }
    else {
        window.addEventListener("load",abc, false);
    }
</script>
```

Please suggest

Comment: Make it easy on yourself; use jquery or any other library!

Comment: i think popup blocker is blocking your script or you have not defined `abc`